# FaceBook Session not set inside controller In codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to capture accesstoken of the facebook user.
the site url in the Fb application is "http://localhost/getinteraction".
I could capture access token. if the redirect url is http://localhost/getinteraction?state=5c604f9ee9096255830c6c7107....etc..

But I need to redirect the return data to the controller in the codeignater..
ex:
http://localhost/getinteraction/fbcontroller

in this point I could not capture the access token ..also

```
$user = $this->facebook->getUser() is false..
```

Comment: Are you taking code from Oauth dialogue box?

Comment: sorry for the late..i want to get access token of the fb user and store it database.i can get it from the  this "http://localhost/getinteraction" URl,and redirect url was the same url.but i chage the redirect url to the "http://localhost/getinteraction/somecontroller" then i cant get the  access token.user id was zero.

Comment: yes ,i'm taking about Oauth dialogue box

Comment: ok let me clear the process here. For your website your going for facebook app Authentication. Once you allow application your are getting back to your website as specified redirect_uri and getting access token in URL. Is this how you are proceeding?

Comment: yes...i build this according to http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/ tutorial..worked well..but if i change the redirect url (inside to another controller)..the session is not set..

Comment: I suppose issue with redirect url. It should be same source. About access tocke if you are getting it in URL in ame parameters like #access_token= ... , you have to use javascript to get token as it's on client side not on serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Session management of Codeigniter is the culprit here. Try changing the codeigniter sessions to database http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html